# How to add a click interceptor in Angular as globally as possible?

Tags: javascript, angular, click, prototype, directive

I'm working on a software that got quite huge over many years and we've noticed there are many buttons (or clickable elements like `<a>` and `<img>`) that aren't safe from double clicks. Since the software is running on sometimes quite laggy hardware (with touch screens that might bug out and register double clicks for no apparent reason) I'd like to implement some kind of global solution for it.

My first thoughts were:

1. Global click listener that gets the click event, processes it and starts a cooldown on that specific element. If another click event is registered before the cooldown is over, it'll just block the event.
2. Changing the click() prototype method of a button or something. I'm not that good with plain JS but I've done something like that for plugins before so I know at least conceptually how that works.
3. Adding a directive that can be inserted into existing elements which need double click protection. This would probably be the "scalpel" method, even though people might just forget to add it. Sadly I have no idea whether my idea is actually possible with directives as I've never implemented one before.
4. Something like a class that can be inherited which handles all clicks. Might be possible to implement together with solutions (1) and/or (2).

Do you have a direction you can point me to to investigate further? Is some kind of global handling for this a good idea at all? Are any/all of the solutions possible at all?

Comment: disable the button on first click, then enable back when api call is done, this will solve your issue!

Comment: It will not, as we have at least 360+ clickable elements in our code (~280 of which are <button> elements) and adding that for every one of them would be too much work.